# Metapost outputtemplate influences %& format comment parsing in verbatimtex

Tags: metapost

Consider the following code:

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%2c.mps";

verbatimtex %&latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1)
  label.lft(btex \textbf{J} etex,origin);
endfig;

end;
```

Why does it not compile when fed to `mpost` as is (because of the space before `%&latex` carrying into the output preventing its parsing as a format comment) but compile fine when the `outputtemplate` line is commented (i.e., the space seems to be gobbled as expected)?

Bonus: If this is a known bug/feature/… a reference to the design rationale would be appreciated.

Note: I am not asking how to make this example compile regardless (I know that I can remove the space before `%&` or put the format comment on a new line). I am specifically asking about the cause of the interaction and its rationale/intention.

Comment: Down at this level of detail, you might get more help on the mailing list... https://www.tug.org/pipermail/metapost/

Comment: @Thruston Thanks for the pointer. I have sent a message there too (linking here) and will post an answer here if I get a useful reply.